# Is there difference in range in dual band routers

Tags: router, wireless-router, dual-band

My home router shows two things -

1. Connect to a 2.4 GHz Wifi
2. Connect to a 5 GHz Wifi
   I found the range of 5 GHz lower than that of 2.4 GHz
   Is that normal or something wrong with the router configuration?

Like right now when I am typing this question the 2.4 GHz shows 2 points or
sometimes 3 points of signal strength whereas the 5 GHz shows just 1 point. 
And sometimes even gives trouble loading websites.
[5GHz properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NzyJ.png)

[2.4GHz properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKsGN.png)

Comment: Yes, this is normal and expected. 5GHz has higher bandwidth and is faster, but has more problems with interference and range. See the answer in the marked duplicate.

Comment: what about 2.4 GHz For my router when I am in the same room as in the router then signal strength is pretty good. But when I am in another room Signal strength drops by 50%. That's weird, The distance is the same but it's just different rooms. Even with 2.4 GHz, this is happening. It's certainly better than 5GHz but still less. Could this be due to some router setting/quality etc issues? One technician came to my house he says it has to do with the structure of the house. Don't know if that's true or he is just saying it. Not sure if I should consider changing the service provider